# Change default value for default property that can still be overridden in interface builder / storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

Lets suppose i want to create a custom ui class that is marked as IBDesignable so i can use it in storyboards, is it possible to override the default value of a default property but still allow for it to be overridden in the storyboard?

For example, if i wanted to create a custom UILabel, can I override it's default backgroundColor to red so that every time i add it to a view in storyboard it will have a red background color by default (instead of the default white it usually has), but if i change the color to anything else in storyboard it will keep that new color.

I know i can add a specific IBInspectable property as a proxy for the backgroundColor, but that's not optimal since that would just leave me with 2 properties on my object that control the same thing (the backgroundColor).

So does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the appearance proxy. It's specifically designed to provide custom defaults for custom subclasses.

The call to the appearance proxy must me done before the storyboard is loaded. One way of doing that is to use the `initialize` class method.

```
class MyCustomLabel: UILabel
{
    override class func initialize() {
        if (self === MyCustomLabel.self) {
            MyCustomLabel.appearance().backgroundColor = .red
        }
    }
}
```

Not all properties can participate in the appearance proxy. Those that can are tagged with the `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` macro in the Objective-C header. One way to display the Objective-C header of a class is to command-click on the class name inside a comment (this is probably a bug actually...)

```
// Copy this comment in you code an click on this: UIView
```

In order to render this default color in Interface builder, you can use the `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` method like so :

```
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    if (self.backgroundColor == nil) {
        self.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

Note that although it will correctly render the background, the color dropdown menu will still show the "default" color.

Comment: This does indeed seem to work, although i get a warning about initialize not being guaranteed to be invoked by Swift so it's probably not a future-proof solution. But what's worse is that it also doesn't show the new default color in the storyboard which is kind of the reason why I want this whole thing

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how you could instruct interface builder to pickup the default color, but maybe it's possible... As for `initialize`, you're right, this is an Objective-C thing and it may behave differently in Swift. Try putting the call in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)` and if that's too late, put it in the `AppDelegate` initializer

Comment: Yes, I'd already tried adding this to the prepareForInterfaceBuilder and although it works to render the correct default color, every time you open the storyboard it unfortunately will render the default color as well for any items that have specifically set another color as background color. Perhaps what i'm asking for is simply impossible, i've at least yet to find a solution for it

Comment: The check for `nil` is important. It will only set the default color if no other color has been specified.